# Formally prove that any number is between two multiples of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given whole integer $x$ and $k$ and positive whole integer $n$.

> Any fixed $x$ is either a multiple of a fixed $n$ or lies between two multiples of $n$: $$ \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} :nk \leq x < nk+n.$$

This statement appears absolutely obvious to me. However, how would you formally correct prove this statement, i.e. derive it from axioms?

Comment: The quotient remainder theorem will go a long way here.  The proof of the quotient remainder theorem is commonly given as an example in an elementary number theory or introduction to proof writing textbook.  If it doesn't appear as that name specifically, search also for a section detailing the Euclidean Division Algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems a bit overpowered for such a simple statement. Couldn't I simply split it into two cases, like (1) x is a multiple, (2) if not, then it lies between two multiples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $k$ is the largest integer such that $nk\le x$. Thus $(k+1)n > x$, otherwise it would contradict our assumption. Thus, $nk \le x < nk+n$. It can be easily shown that $k=[\frac{x}{n}]$, where $[y]$ is the greatest integer function.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the Division Algorithm, which says that $\forall n,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\exists! q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 ≤ r < d$ such that
$$n = qd + r$$

Let $x,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. In our case, we need to use the Division Algorithm with $x$ as the dividend and $n$ as the divisor. Then by the Division Algoirthm, $\exists! k,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 \le r < n$ such that $x = nk + r$. Since we have $r \ge 0$, $x$ must satisfy $x \ge nk$, and since $r < n$, $x$ must satisfy $x < nk + n$.

It now follows that $nk \le x < nk + n$.

Comment: I wonder if someone who needs to be reminded of the statement of the division algorithm will know what $\exists!$ means.  Or put another way, your answer seems to be addressed to a reader who knows what $\exists !$ means but not what the division algorithm is, and I am not sure that such a person exists.

Comment: OP seems to know what "$\exists$" means since he uses it in his question, so I would imagine that at worst, he was just one step away from googling "$\exists!$" to find out that it means "there exists unique". You make a fair point though. I should've been more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

$$nk \le x \lt nk + n$$
$$0 \le x - nk \lt n$$

By the Quotient Remainder Theorem, or modular arithmetic

$$0 \le x \mod n \lt n$$

Which is true